# Kotlin string date formatter

Tags: string, kotlin, parsing

I'm trying to parse string date

```
"AuthDate": "2021-08-19T23:40:52+04:00",
```

here is code for parsing and displaying

```
var date = item?.authDate.toString()
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz")
val parsedDate = formatter.parse(date)
val displayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:MM:SS")
text = displayFormatter.format(parsedDate).toString()
```

This works fine, except one thing, Seconds is always displayed in "00".

For example, if authDate is `2021-08-19T23:40:52+04:00`,

displayed authDate is `2021-08-19, 23:40:00`

not `23:40:52` as I want.

Comment: `"ss" != "SS"`.

Comment: thanks man it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz")
...
val displayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:MM:SS")
```

Notice how the first of these uses `mm` and `ss`, while the second uses `MM` and `SS`. The former says to parse hours, minutes, then seconds. The latter says to display hours, the month, and then the fraction of a second. See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for a full list of the specifiers, but you're probably looking for

```
val displayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss")
```